# asypmtotic series of $\tan x$ in terms of $x \cos x$

Tags: calculus, analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I have come across an asymptotic series of $\tan x$ in the form of
$\tan x \sim x\cos x + \frac{5}{6}(x\cos x)^3 + \frac{161}{120}(x\cos x)^5$ as $x\to 0$, but I have no idea how this is derived.
I am only familiar with the result $\tan x \sim x + x^3/3 + 2/15 x^5$ by Taylor expansion.
How is the expansion around $x\cos x$ obtained?

Comment: Let $u=x\cos x$. Calculate $d^(n)(\tan x)/du^n|_{x=0}$ I think you can reproduce the coefficients. Keep in mind $df/du=(df/dx)/(du/dx)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $x\cos(x)=x-\frac12x^3+\frac1{24}x^5+O(x^7)$.

So, what is the expansion of $x\cos(x)+\frac56 (x\cos(x))^3+\frac1{20}(x\cos(x))^5$?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bürmann's theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BuermannsTheorem.html) with $f(x)=\tan x$, $\phi(x)=x\cos x$, $a=b=0$, to obtain
$$
\tan x = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}^{2n} \sec ^{2n + 3} t}}{{{\rm d}t^{2n} }}} \right]_{t = 0} \frac{{(x\cos x)^{2n + 1} }}{{(2n + 1)!}}} 
$$
for sufficiently small values of $x$.